# How do I access and run command line on a remote host FOR IDIOTS?

Tags: command-line

I don't have much command line fu, but I need to download a PHP extension onto a remote host. ( I've just Googled around and not found much help, strangely ).

I'm on OSX .. have iTerm .. but so far have just used it for basic localhost stuff and cut'n'pasted anything vaguely advanced.

So can someone give me a quick talk through?  If my site is mysite.com, how do I access it through my CLI?

I thought this might do it >

```
ssh username@mysite.com  
-or-
ssh -l username xx.xx.xx.xxx
```

But it doesn't.  Just times out with "port:22: Operation timed out"

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Is it possible the host doesn't even allow connection?  Would I receive a different error message?  How do I tell?

And just so I know, from the point that I am hypothetically connected, all commands will be run as if I am on the remote until I end the session, correct?

Comment: I think it's a question more fitting on SuperUser than StackOverflow.